# Impala query taking longer time in analyzing and planning

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, impala, hive-metastore

I have two separate Hadoop clusters, Cloudera Hadoop cluster and Apache Hadoop cluster.
Found that Impala query runs faster on Cloudera whereas same query runs slower in Apache Hadoop cluster.
During query execution found that query taking significant amount of time in analyzing and Planning phase compared to Cloudera cluster.
I tuned up Apache cluster for heap size configuration and try to maintain same property and it’s values as I have in Cloudera Cluster.

What else I need to double check or need to configure some other services, configurations?
Please suggest.

Same machine hardware configuration and same instances were used in both clusters.

Versions I used in Cloudera:-
hive-common-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar,
CDH 6.3.2 and
impalad version 3.2.0

Versions I used in Apache:-
hive-common-2.1.1-cdh6.x-SNAPSHOT.jar,
Hadoop 3.0.0 and
Impala 3.4.0

Further I added some properties to improve the query performance, but no use

#Impala Catalog Server

```
export JAVA_TOOLS_OPTIONS="-Xmx8g"


hive-env.sh
export HIVE_CLIENT_HEAPSIZE=1024
export HIVE_METASTORE_HEAPSIZE=8192
export HIVE_SERVER2_HEAPSIZE=8192
export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=8192
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.client.read.shortcircuit</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.domain.socket.path</name>
    <value>/data/var/run/hdfs-sockets/dn</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.client.file-block-storage-locations.timeout.millis</name>
    <value>10000</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.hdfs-blocks-metadata.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Additional configuration is needed. Hive metastore version? Etc.

Comment: On Apache Cluster
hive-common-2.1.1-cdh6.x-SNAPSHOT.jar

On Cloudera cluster
hive-common-2.1.1-cdh6.3.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions on comparison of two clusters: 1- check the catalog server heap size and stestore heap size. 2- check query coordinator mem_limit. 3- check hdfs namenode heap size. 4- check short circuit read is true on impalad. 5- check hive metastore heap sizes. Also; what is the difference of invalidate speeds of two clusters? What about the timing of hdfs command file listing on two clusters?

Comment: Added some properties and tuned the heap size, but no use.
Detail mentioned in the post

Comment: want to share detail 'summary' of Impala query. How to share